# Get detail info about PostgreSql error for automatic parse

Tags: postgresql, error-handling

For example I have NOT NULL field in database. I'm trying to insert NULL VALUE into it. PostgreSQL says:
`ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

(or something like that, in my version it speeks in russian, so i find english error message in google).

How can i obtain additional information about error? Firts of all table and schema. I have to parse this error and return table, schema and field where error occurred to a higher module of my system. This info is quite easy to find in Oracle and SQL Server, but how to find them in postgre?

Same trouble with UNIQUE VIOLATION ERROR and others.

**Note:** this insert or update may be part of big batch command so without information from database I can't locate query where error occurred.

Comment: Which frontend program are you using? ( in psql you could use \d to get table definitions) BTW: the error meaasges you give seemed rather obvious to me. BTW: in most cases, the English error messages (for *any* program) are good search terms for google, which seems a good reason to prefer English versions.

Comment: About english i know, thanks. About "rather obvious". Task is: when error occurres atomaticly say to higher module "Error in shema XX table YY field ZZ". I can't find this info in Postgre error defenition.

As client i use npgsql driver.

Comment: If you are using some kind of interface to embedded SQL: you might want to take a look into the (standardised) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/errcodes-appendix.html errorcodes, the SQLCA might offer additional contextual information : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-errors.html#ECPG-SQLCA . I don't know the npgsql driver, but all the drivers lean on the definition in the esql managers. (they may or may not *use* all the info there, but that's another matter ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a regular expressions and parse error message. There are not other possibility now. This is in my ToDo, but it needs a free time.

Comment: Yes, i'm using RegExp for parse error. But UNIQUE VIOLATION ERROR and NOT NULL VIOLATION ERROR error message doesn't contains this info.

Only `ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`
There is no info in witch table "id" is located.